# Is 5.6 radians equivalent to 1.2 theta?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, circles, area, angle

So I was studying some circle properties in Khan Academy and this problem basically states that if:

$S=r\theta$

then find a formula for $S$ in terms of $r$. Now in the problem it says that the angle equals 5.6 radians but then the answer says that:

$S=r(1.2)$

The problem says this... right below the circle (the angle of the image it's a central angle in radians)

Step 1: A central angle $\theta$ measured in radians tells us how many times the radius fits in the arc

$\text{arc longitude} = \text{radius} * \theta$

Step 2: Substitute

$S= r * 1.2$ <---- ????

Step 3: Formula it's:

$S= r * 1.2$

Why is it 1.2????

[Khan Academy radians problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyoNE.png)

Comment: At a first glance, it looks like a typo to me. Certainly I would plug in $\theta = 5.6$ as interpreted from the picture.

Comment: Yeah.. damn Khan Academy, I spent like 2 hours looking for an answer when I thought the same at the beginning... xD

Comment: Perhaps you can send them a message so that they can correct the error.

Comment: I always do :3 thanks!